# How can I set values for every field in form with Symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony, session-variables

I made a search form where it is possible to select 'bigcity' and 'category'. In SearchController.php, I set a session so that when I come back to search page, I retrieve values that I selected. I tried to set these values in `{{ form(form) }}` written in search.html.twig.

It works properly for 'bigcity' but not for 'category'. Where could be the mistake ?

**search.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}

{{ form_start(form) }}
            <p>Où souhaites-tu faire une sortie ou une activité ?</p>
            {{ form_widget(form.bigcity, {'attr' : {'class' : 'mb-3' }, 'value' : app.session.get('searchFormData').bigcity.id} ) }}
            <p>Quel type de sortie ou d’activité t’intéresse ?</p>
            {{ form_widget(form.category, {'attr' : {'class' : 'mb-3' }, 'value' : app.session.get('searchFormData').category.id} ) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.save, {'label': 'Je valide'} ) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

** SearchController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Front;

use App\Form\SearchType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class SearchController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/search', name: 'search')]
    public function search(
        Request $request, 
        SessionInterface $sessionInterface,
        EventRepository $eventRepository,
    ){   
        $searchFormData  = $sessionInterface->get('searchFormData');

        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, ['data' => $searchFormData]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $data = $form->getData();
            $sessionInterface->set('searchFormData', $data);
            $events = $eventRepository->findAll();
            
            return $this->redirectToRoute("events", [
                'bigcity'=> $form->get('bigcity')->getData()->getId(), 
                'category'=> $form->get('category')->getData()->getId(), 
                'events' => $events
            ]);
        }
        return $this->renderForm('front/search.html.twig', [ 
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**SearchType.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\BigCity;
use App\Entity\Category;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class SearchType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('bigcity', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => BigCity::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionne une grande ville',
            ])
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Category::class,
                'choice_label' => 'image',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have set the data in the controller, you should not have to set the values in the template, try one way then the other and explain what happens in each scenario.

Comment: Please show which Symfony version you are using.

Comment: Hi Arleigh Hix. I am using Symfony 6.0.2.

Comment: When I take values from ```{{ form(form) }}```, I don't have the 'bigcity' value setted any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in SearchType category has 'expanded' => true, that's why it works with bigcity but not with catgory. What you can do is something like this:

```
{{ form_label(form.category) }}
{% for key, categoryItem in form.category.children %}
    {{ form_widget(categoryItem, {'attr' : {'class' : 'mb-3' },  'checked': categoryItem.vars.value ==  app.session.get('searchFormData').category.id ? 'checked' : ''  } ) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Once again, that worked very well. Thank you for your help hous. :)

Comment: Good, very well :)